# Improving a Haskell FizzBuzz Solution

Tags: haskell, fizzbuzz

I wrote a solution to the popularized [FizzBuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) problem in Haskell to see how a functional solution looks. I'm more or less happy with my solution, except for the definition of `list`. It just looks sort of contorted.

*Are there any language features in Haskell which can improve the readability of this code, especially the definition of `list`, while preserving the extensibility that `table` provides?*

```
import Control.Arrow

main = mapM_ (putStrLn . fizzBuzzLogic) [1..100]

fizzBuzzLogic :: Int -> String
fizzBuzzLogic x
  | null list = show x
  | otherwise = foldl1 (++) list
  where
    list  = map snd . filter ((==0) .fst) $ map (first (mod x)) table
    table = [(3,"Fizz")
            ,(5,"Buzz")
            ] --add more modulo tokens if you wish
```

Comment: Instead of `foldl1 (++)` use `concat`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You write:

```
map snd . filter ((==0) .fst) $ map (first (mod x)) table
```

To make it clearer that we have three operations applied one after another, I would rather write:

```
map snd . filter ((==0) .fst) . map (first (mod x)) $ table
```

But I think this gets easier to read if we merge the `filter` and the second `map`:

```
map snd . filter ((== 0) . mod x . fst) $ table
```

Some people prefer pointful style, that is, they prefer `\` over `.`:

```
map snd . filter (\(number, text) -> x `mod` number == 0) $ table
```

Personally, I would prefer a list comprehension here:

```
[text | (number, text) <- table, x `mod` number == 0]
```

Comment: I agree, the list comprehension is a much clean solution here! Thanks for the detailed input!

Comment: Is there an official style guide statement for `op $ op $ op $ arg` vs `op . op . op $ arg`? I tend to prefer the former.

Comment: @JanDvorak `$` is considered visually noisier than `.`. Also, `.` resembles mathematical operator ∘ for function composition. Since functional languages are largely about the composition of functions, the `.` operator is preferred also for academic reasons. Also `$` and `.` have different operator precedence so they are not always interchangeable!